# Using the # inside a CSS id declaration

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

Normally i would only use alphanumeric with - and _ in any html class or id attribute, but i wondered whether it was possible it include a # in the middle of an attribute, e.g:

`<div id = "my_css_id_#f4ed11">`

I wont't be a targeting this through CSS, this is purely for javasrcipt.

***NOTE*** The reason I am asking it not because I want to do this, but because of some related PHP code done by someone it would make this part of the project easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. It’s valid as per HTML5.

You’ll simply need to [escape the character in a selector (for use in CSS or JavaScript)](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes). For the `#` character, it’s quite simple; you can just use `\#`.

Here’s a tool that will tell you how to escape any character in a CSS/JS selector: http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0foo%23bar From that page:

```
<script>
  // document.getElementById or similar
  document.getElementById('foo#bar');
  // document.querySelector or similar
  $('#foo\\#bar');
</script>
```

[image]

P.S. On the subject of weird characters in ID or `class` values: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend doing that. It would be difficult to access an element with ID #...#... via CSS or even Javascript as you noted since # is so overloaded in programming/coding.

It sounds like you want to store some piece of data. You are aware that W3C standards allow attributes that begin with `data-` right?

For instance, you could keep a piece of data associated with an element as such:

```
<p data-name="John Jones">I like alliteration.</p>
```

This article details data attributes effectively.
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to do trial and error and see if it works. But, in terms of pseudo-selectors, there should be no problem with have the # symbol. To select you would use:

```
$("#my_css_id_#f4ed11")
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The selector you’re proposing would attempt to select the element that has both the `id="my_css_id_"` and `id="f4ed11"`, which is impossible in HTML. (Assuming `$` is jQuery, or any other JavaScript library that uses `document.querySelectorAll` when available. `document.getElementById('my_css_id_#f4ed11')` would work, though.)